# Java with generics confusion

Tags: java, generics

I cannot figure out the proper way to do this with generics.  I have a class, `Foo`, which has a generic (`Foo<class>`).  I then want to have a map of `Map<String, Foo>`.  Now, I can do this, and add `Foo<String>` as one map item, and `Foo<Integer>` as another.  However, when I use the map's get method, I just get a `Foo` back and the type can no longer be inferred, so if I do:

```
String s = map.get("StringFoo")
```

I get a compile error and have to do:

String s = (String) map.get("StringFoo")

What is a good pattern for doing something like this to avoid the casting, since that is what generics are for in the first place.  I may be able to do something like `Map<String, Foo<?>>`, but is that the way to do it?

Details of my code follow, this can be put into a directory and `javac *.java && java Main` will run it.

I have a generic java class in Foo.java,

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    T value;

    public T getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(T t)
    {
        this.value = t;
    }
}
```

Now, I have the following test class in Main.java:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] a)
        {
            Foo<String> fooStr = new Foo<String>();
            fooStr.setValue("TEST 123");

            Foo<Integer> fooInt = new Foo<Integer>();
            fooInt.setValue(314159);

            Map<String, Foo> mapOfFoo = new HashMap<String, Foo>();

            mapOfFoo.put("Strings", fooStr);
            mapOfFoo.put("Integer", fooInt);

            System.out.println("All set");

            String s = mapOfFoo.get("Strings").getValue();

            System.out.println("Got: " + s);

        }
}
```

When I compile this, I get the following error:

```
Main.java:21: error: incompatible types
            String s = mapOfFoo.get("Strings").getValue();
                                                       ^
  required: String
  found:    Object
1 error
```

When I do this in Main.java, it works:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] a)
        {
            Foo<String> fooStr = new Foo<String>();
            fooStr.setValue("TEST 123");

            Foo<Integer> fooInt = new Foo<Integer>();
            fooInt.setValue(314159);

            Map<String, Foo> mapOfFoo = new HashMap<String, Foo>();

            mapOfFoo.put("Strings", fooStr);
            mapOfFoo.put("Integer", fooInt);

            System.out.println("All set");

            String s = (String)mapOfFoo.get("Strings").getValue();

            System.out.println("Got: " + s);

        }
}
```

I'm not sure what the best practice is for something like this.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: OK, my code got botched there at the beginning because it stripped some of my &gt; and &lt; tags, but the example code should get the point across

Comment: Just use the four-space indents; ordinary angle brackets work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of construct is actually not uncommonly needed in Java, the problem is that generic parameters are a compile-time-only feature, and that map-retrieval is a run-time-only feature, so there's no way for the compiler to understand your rule and not raise a warning about it somewhere.

The safest way to implement a structure like this is through a wrapper class, which logically guarantees type safety, and all you have to do is throw a `SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the getter.

```
public class FooMapper {

  private Map<Class<?>, Foo<?>> fooMap = new HashMap<>();

  public <T> void setFoo(Class<T> clazz, Foo<T> foo) {
    fooMap.put(clazz, foo);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <T> Foo<T> getFoo(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (Foo<T>) fooMap.get(clazz);
  }

}
```

This wrapper guarantees that you can never put a `Foo` of the wrong type with the wrong `Class` object, so the 'unchecked' cast can never possibly fail.

Comment: That looks like what I want to do, but I get 2 compile errors: `FooMapper.java:5: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public <T> setFoo(Class<T> clazz, Foo<T> foo) {
               ^
FooMapper.java:10: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public <T> getFoo(Class<T> clazz) {
               ^`

Comment: Ah, that was a trivial oversight by me.  Fixed now

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be using a non-generic Foo in your Map declaration and construction. Instead this:

```
Map<String, Foo> mapOfFoo = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
```

Should be this:

```
Map<String, Foo<String>> mapOfFoo = new HashMap<String, Foo<String>>();
```

Then you won't have to cast to String -- one of the reasons to use generics in the first place, and `Foo#getValue()` will return a String unequivocally.

Comment: Well, that defeats the purpose.  If you look at the code, I add both `Foo<String>` and `Foo<Integer>` to the `Map<String, Foo>`, and that's where I run into problems.

Comment: @user1022260: ah, so I see. Then your design is broken, and you shouldn't be creating such a construct where you have to cast. If you absolutely need that, then use indirection one more time and create a Map that takes the Type parameter used.